# Check the status on dial-pad during call session

Tags: android, android-fragments, phone-call

I want to check whether the dialpad is activated or not during the call session. I am making an idea for simple application which needs to know the status of dial-pad during call session.

Any code snippet or link to tuts will be helpful.

Thank you in advanced.

**Note:** Sorry, for not posting the code snippet because I am in the initial phase and stuck in this process so I have no codes to show.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by Obtaining the internal `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony` object using Java reflection. And use `showCallScreen();` or `showCallScreenWithDialpad`

```
   /**
     * If there is currently a call in progress, show the call screen.
     * The DTMF dialpad may or may not be visible initially, depending on
     * whether it was up when the user last exited the InCallScreen.
     *
     * @return true if the call screen was shown.
     */
    boolean showCallScreen();

    /**
     * Variation of showCallScreen() that also specifies whether the
     * DTMF dialpad should be initially visible when the InCallScreen
     * comes up.
     *
     * @param showDialpad if true, make the dialpad visible initially,
     * otherwise hide the dialpad initially.
     * @return true if the call screen was shown.
     *
     * @see showCallScreen
     */
    boolean showCallScreenWithDialpad(boolean showDialpad);
```

Create the package name com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony and put `ITelephony.aidl` files with above method. When you compile same methods will be created under `gen` directory with same package name. Then you can use this method like.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
ITelephony telephonyService;
telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(tm);

// Silence the ringer and answer the call!
telephonyService.showCalScreen();
```

But may be this will not work on above Android 2.2+, i haven't tried but you can try if it works. on Android 2.2+ it gives security exception sometimes. Below is the link for that.

[Neither user 10056 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019975/neither-user-10056-nor-current-process-has-android-permission-modify-phone-state?lq=1)